# Why do we call this transformation non-singular?

Tags: linear-algebra, definition, linear-transformations

In linear algebra books, the authors call the linear transformation $T$ with the property

$$T(\alpha)=0\implies \alpha=0$$

non-singular.

What's the motivation behind the term "non-singular"?

Comment: This is bad terminology. The right terminology for this condition is injective or one-to-one. "Nonsingular" is typically used to mean bijective or invertible (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Kunze and Hoffman's book use both terms.  This gives me an impression that there are other types of function such that these terms are not equivalent.

Comment: @user42912 They are equivalent on finite-dimensional spaces, but not for infinite-dimensional spaces.

Comment: Historically, the term "singular" was used to describe a square matrix rather than a linear transformation. A singular matrix means a square matrix with zero determinant. As matrices usually have nonzero determinant and such matrices have behave more nicely, matrices with zero determinants were considered exceptional, hence the term "singular".

Answer (score 7):

Suppose $Tv=0$ implies $v=0$. It follows immediately that $T$ is *injective* since if $Tv_{1}=Tv_{2}$ then $Tv_{1}-Tv_{2}=T(v_{1}-v_{2})=0$ and hence $v_{1}-v_{2}=0$, or equivalently $v_{1}=v_{2}$. Therefore, we can unambiguously define $T^{-1}$ on the range of $T$.

The author might be calling $T$ nonsingular because it "comes with" a well-defined inverse (at least on the range of $T$).

**Edit** As QiaochuYuan points out, this could be considered bad terminology. Usually nonsingular is reserved for (in addition to $T$ being injective) when the range of $T$ is the whole codomain.

Comment: Why do we call a function with a well-defined inverse by "nonsingular"? thanks

Comment: That's more etymology than anything. I would guess because "nonsingular" makes it sound like the operator "comes with" another operator, namely its inverse (i.e., singular = all alone, no other friendly operators to hang out with).